# Is it possibe to convert an existing PCIe gen3.0 x16 Graphics card to PCIe gen4 x8 without sacrificing the bandwidth

Tags: pci-express

Since PCIe gen4 x8 speed(15.754 GB/s - source from WikiPedia) is equal to PCIe gen3 x16. Is there any converters available to do this??

for example I have an 11900k or 5900x with 2 GPU's(for PCIe pass-through) which are PCIe gen3 x16 and the CPU/Motherboard is capable bifurcating an gen4 x16 slot into two gen4 x8. if I connect an gen3 x16 GPU it will work in gen3 x8 speed.(I know performance impact is quite less)

so the bandwidth is reduced because of the PCIe versions. Is there any possibilities to do the conversion or it is limited by the PCIe hardware/UEFI in them?

Comment: No, what you want isn’t possible

Comment: Thanks for the Answer..
Can I know why that is...any source/ documents would be helpful